# constexpr, string_view and find

Tags: c++, constexpr, string-view

I have just written this code:

```
bool is_name_char(char c)
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;
    constexpr const auto not_name = "[]<>/("sv;
    constexpr const auto b = std::begin(not_name);
    constexpr const auto e = std::end(not_name);
    return (e == std::find(b, e, c)) && (0x21 <= c && c <= 0x7e);
}
```

(A function supposed to accept characters in the range `[0x21, 0x7e]`, if they are not black-listed).

Debugging this code in Visual Studio 2019 (@ version 16.7.2) makes VS complain that `b` and `e` are not from the same sequence.

Am I making a wrong assumption here, or is this not supposed to work?

Comment: Note: An implementation without `constexpr` works as expected.

Comment: Works with clang with no problem

Comment: I am building this as a cmake project (but I don't think it should make a difference).

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is constexpr only since C++20, and its seems not updated for all compilers/std-libraries [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EWW3dT). With custom one, it works with lastest versions of gcc/clang/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c5o5Ys).